# Is there any way to use code snippets feature of SQL Server to call stored procedure with it`s parameters with null value?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, code-snippets

I have a stored procedure with several parameters and I call it every time like below code:

```
EXEC sp_General_AutoIncrement 
    @tbl_Name = 'tbl_General_MenuParents',
    @fld_Name = 'MenuParent_Code',
    @startWith = 1,
    @new_ID = @MenuParent_Code OUTPUT;
```

My question is:

Is there any way to use code snippets feature to create calling stored procedure or function with null or empty parameters and create the code quickly like this:

```
EXEC sp_General_AutoIncrement 
    @tbl_Name = '',
    @fld_Name = '',
    @startWith = 0,
    @new_ID = @MenuParent_Code OUTPUT;
```

What`s your idea?

Thank you for your attentions.

Comment: You can give the default value while creating a procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Default you just can :

```
Right Click > Script > Execute To
```

But, There is plenty of commercial product options out there:

```
Apex, SSM-Booster and RedGate SQL Prompt.
```

That you can define custom snippet.

Comment: Thanks you. RedGate SQL prompt is exactly the one that I want. but I can't buy it because of sanctions :( Is there any free tool?

Comment: We are living in same place, bro (Dadash), So use this : https://soft98.ir/software/programming/3978-redgate-sql-toolbelt-bundle.html

Comment: I'm so glad to hear about it. But my SQL Server version is 2019 and I think the tool you mentioned is too old to working with it. Of course I didn't check it yet.

Comment: Try this: https://www.irdevelopers.com/en/Product/18222-redgate-sql-toolbelt or https://www.fakhravari.ir/download/database/redgate-sql-toolbelt-2019-v2-3-1-2610